# Bash script with selective root permissions for commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to have a bash script invoked with root permissions to run different commands with different privileges?

Right now i have a script which runs a C-program with root permissions and creates a folder and some files which i want to have non-root permissions. Looking at the man page i see that the mkdir command takes a permissions parameter but i was wondering whether there's a smarter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the man pages for the `chmod` and `chown` commands. Depending on what you are trying to do, either one of these should be our solution.

If you want to change the directory ownership to a user/group other than root, use `chown -R user:group [directory]` to recursively change ownership. If you just want the permissions changed, but with root still in ownership then use `chmod -R 754 [directory]`; keep in mind you will need to alter the permissions to suit your needs.

Comment: That would work for folder and files only, right? I'm looking for changing the permissions associated for any command that I put in the script.

Comment: What do you mean by folder and files? *everything in Linux is a file*. Could you perhaps provide a bit more clarity into your objective.